# Calculate combinations of several categorical variables

Tags: r, combinations, categorical-data

I have a data frame with mainly categorical variables. I want to see the number of combinations of variables found in three of these columns with categorical variables.
The data in the columns looks like this:

```
number_arms <- c("6","8","12")
arrangements <- c("single", "paired", "ornament")
approx_position <- c("top", "middle", "bottom")
rg2 <- data.frame(number_arms, arrangements, approx_position)
```

I was reading in another post to use the following code when comparing two columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
rg2 %>%
     count(combination = str_c(pmin(number_arms, arrangements), ' - ',
       pmax(number_arms, arrangements)), name = "count")
```

This is the result:

```
combination   count
12 - single    1            
16 - single    1            
4 - paired     3            
4 - single     4            
5 - paired     4            
5 - single     2            
6 - ornament   1            
6 - paired    81
```

However, the code does not give me the wanted results if I add the third column, like this:

```
rg2 %>%
     count(combination = str_c(pmin(number_arms, arrangements, approx_position), ' - ',
       pmax(number_arms, arrangements, approx_position)), name = "count")
```

It still runs the code without error but I get wrong results.
Do I need a different code to calculate the combinations of three variables?

Comment: So what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: The result should look like the previous result, just with the third variable included as well.
`combination       count
12 - single top        1                    
4 - paired bottom   3                           
6 - paired middle    81`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the count of each combination of the variables, excluding 0, you can do:

```r
subset(data.frame(table(rg2)), Freq > 0)

   number_arms arrangements approx_position Freq
1           12     ornament          bottom    1
15           8       paired          middle    1
26           6       single             top    1
```

or combined:

```r
subset(data.frame(table(rg2)), Freq > 0) |>
  tidyr::unite("combn", -Freq, sep = " - ")

                    combn Freq
1  12 - ornament - bottom    1
15    8 - paired - middle    1
26       6 - single - top    1
```

data

```r
number_arms <- c("6","8","12")
arrangements <- c("single", "paired", "ornament")
approx_position <- c("top", "middle", "bottom")
rg2 <- data.frame(number_arms, arrangements, approx_position)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like the combined version better but it only works if I write %>% instead of  |>.

Comment: |> has been introduced recently in R, that’s maybe why

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse option (updated to remove `group_by`):

```
library(dplyr)

rg2 %>%
  count(number_arms, arrangements, approx_position)
```

Result:

```
 number_arms arrangements approx_position     n
  <chr>       <chr>        <chr>           <int>
1 12          ornament     bottom              1
2 6           single       top                 1
3 8           paired       middle              1
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works very well too. I like the combined version of Mael better though because I want to create a barplot from the result. Sorry, should have specified that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `dplyr::count()` + `paste()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

rg2 %>%
  count(combination = paste(number_arms, arrangements, approx_position, sep = " - "), name = "count")

#              combination count
# 1 12 - ornament - bottom     1
# 2       6 - single - top     1
# 3    8 - paired - middle     1
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works very well too. But I like Mael's code better because this one here include all combinations including NAs. I'd rather only have options without NAs. Should have specified earlier but I only realized this now.